# MongoDB UserNotFound when starting mongod

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I have a MongoDB version `2.4` that i wish to upgrade to `4.0`. The official solution is to upgrade from `2.4` to `2.6`, then to `3.0`, and so on.
I am attempting to upgrade from `2.6` to `3.0`, and also to change the storage engine to `WiredTiger` .

To upgrade from `2.6` to `3.0` i changed the bin folder's name of the `2.6`executables and then changed the `3.0` bin folder's name to bin (so i will have a seamless transition to `3.0`). Then as [This official MongoDB upgrade manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/) says, i am trying to change the storage engine to `WiredTiger` by using [This manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-standalone-wiredtiger/).

However, when i run this command:

```
mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath ../dataDb_WiredTiger
```

as suggested by the manual, i get an error:

> SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for MyAdminUser on admin ;
> UserNotFound Could not find user MyAdminUser@admin
>
> Failed to authenticate MyAdminUser@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user MyAdminUser@admin

But using MongoVUE or shell, i am able to authenticate using the same user.

What am i missing here?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up working by using a configuration file when running mongod. Don't know why.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/126838)

Comment: This is my post. By using a configuration file it 'probably' overrides any default configuration used, and then it doesnt try to auth with an unexisting user (because im using new database, how would it exist in the first place?).